# downloading images through a javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have developed a simple web site which will download a image file form a server 
in my web page I have a "download" button. When I click on it following is the code I used to download the image file:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    downloadLink.href =  $scope.urlValue2 + "&downloadName=" + fileName + ".jpg";
    downloadLink.download = fileName+'.jpg';
    downloadLink.type = 'image/jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
```

This is working fine in chrome but in firefox this is not working. What might be the problem?

Comment: Install Firebug and check the console for error messages. That might give you a clue.

Comment: @khattam it is downloading the file but the file type is not changing to .jpg its file type is 'file'

Comment: i have installed firebug and try to figure it out but i don't have any clue

Comment: Does the header (for the image file) output proper file type?

Comment: yes it is saved properly when i used open with (windows photo viewer) but when i used save file option the file type changes to type file

Comment: Which operating system are you using ? Which browser version ?

Comment: operating system is windows and browser version is FF25

Comment: The problem is not because of the js code but because of the server serving the file. I don't think it has proper headers. Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: i found the problem my file name is like this 
**somefile_somename something.jpeg** when i replace the white space with a norther underscore **(now my file name is like somefile_somename_something.jpeg)** not it is working fine
i don't know the reason but it's working is anyone know the correct answer to the scenario

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image), the correct MIME type for JPEG images is `image/jpeg`

Try to replace `'image/jpg'` with `'image/jpeg'`

Comment: still it giving  the same output

Comment: @madu, have you tried the HTML5 [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute?

Comment: @Aurelien afaik the `type` attribute has never actually done anything at all. I guess the thinking is that it might be useful for something at some point in the future.